# Scala: Option, Some and the ArrowAssoc operator

Tags: scala

I am trying to analyze the following piece of Scala code:

```
import java.nio.file._
import scala.Some

abstract class MyCustomDirectoryIterator[T](path:Path,someNumber:Int, anotherNum:Int) extends Iterator[T] {

def getCustomIterator(myPath:Path):Option[(DirectoryStream[Path],
                                                 Iterator[Path])] = try {
  //we get the directory stream        
   val str = Files.newDirectoryStream(myPath)
    //then we get the iterator out of the stream
    val iter = str.iterator()
    Some((str -> iter))
  } catch {
    case de:DirectoryIteratorException =>
      printstacktrace(de.getMessage)
      None

  }
```

---

How do I interpert this piece of code: `Some((str -> iter))`
Yes, it is returning a value of type:

```
Option[(DirectoryStream[Path], Iterator[Path])]
```

The -> operator is, to the best of my understanding, ArrowAssoc from the scala.Predef package.

```
implicit final class ArrowAssoc[A] extends AnyVal
```

But I still do not understand what the -> thing is doing to give me a return value of type:

```
Option[(DirectoryStream[Path], Iterator[Path])]
```

Can the Scala experts out here throw more light on this? Is there any way to write the "Some(..)" thing in a more readable way? I do understand the role played by Some, though.

Comment: I don't think there's any nicer way of expressing it except using a comma instead of `->`. Why on earth is `scala.Some` being imported? Overzealous IDE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `->` operator just creates a tuple:

```
scala> 1 -> "one"
res0: (Int, String) = (1,one)
```

which is equivalent to

```
scala> (1, "one")
res1: (Int, String) = (1,one)
```

I was just going to add the source code, but Reactormonk has got there first ;-)

The `->` method is made available on any object via the implicit ArrowAssoc class. Calling it on an object of type `A`, passing a parameter of type `B`, creates a `Tuple2[A, B]`.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer as the correct answer since you did say what the return type was. How @ReactorMonk's answer is pretty good too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Both answers are equally right on target. I appreciate it

Answer (score 12):

The usual case for the `->` operator is

```
Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")
```

which is the same as

```
Map((1, "foo"), (2, "bar"))
```

Which works because the signature for `Map.apply` is

```
def apply[A, B](elems: Tuple2[A, B]*): Map[A, B]
```

which means it takes tuples as arguments and constructs a `Map` from
it.

So

```
(1 -> "foo")
```

is equivalent to

```
(1, "foo")
```

From the compiler sources:

```
implicit final class ArrowAssoc[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  @inline def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(self, y)
  def →[B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = ->(y)
}
```

which tells you directly it's creating a tuple. And that `1 → "foo"` works as well.

Comment: I am a little confused. @Dan says, the -> operator creates a Tuple. In your Map examples you have given, 1 -> "food", the key value pair is a tuple that one passes to create a Map?

Comment: Thanks much. Your answer is very detailed and hits the mark on target. After seeking clarification about the Tuple,  you added a lot more context, and consolidated my understanding after @Dan answered.